# Registering a COM server to have admin privileges

Tags: c#, windows, com

I have an application that relies on a COM server.

```
string exePath = "path\\to\\exe.exe";

string regString = String.Format("SOFTWARE\\Classes\\CLSID\\{{{0}}}\\LocalServer32", someGuid);

var key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(regString);

key.SetValue(null, exePath);
```

However, when the exe is fired by the com server, the exe does not have admin privileges, and therefore cannot do things like silent install an msi, create a text file in the ProgramFiles directory, etc.

How can I configure my com server to have admin privileges?

Comment: When I set the compatibility to "Run this program as administrator", the COM server is unable to run the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish this, you need to use the COM Elevation Moniker.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679687(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help!